# firebug TypeError: array element is null

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a file which contains a list of emails addresses and a CSV file which contains the list of some of the addresses with more information such as names, title etc.

I am trying to compare the two files by check each line of the csv file. If the email in a line of the csv file matches any email in the email list the line is pushed to another array.

I came up with the following code:

```
function getCsvMatches(){
  var holder = [];
  var sep = "\n";
  var match_holder = "";
  var csv = document.getElementById("rawdata2").value;
  var csv_array = csv.split('\n');

  var email_list = document.getElementById("rawdata1").value;
  var emaillist_array = email_list.split('\n');

  var csv_length = csv_array.length;
  var emaillist_length = email_list.length;    

  for (var  i = 0; i < csv_length; i++){
    var email_line = csv_array[i].match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)[0];
    //alert(email_line) //this works as expected
    if(emaillist_array.indexOf(email_line)>= 0){
      holder.push(csv_array[i]);
    }
  }

  for (var n = 0; n < holder.length; n++) {
    matched_holder += holder[n];
    matched_holder += sep;    
  }   

document.extractor3.rawdata3.value = match_holder;
document.extractor3.match_count.value =  holder.length;
document.extractor1.emaillist_count.value = emaillist_length;
document.extractor2.csv_count.value = csv_length;

}
```

Here jsbin link for more code and html: http://jsbin.com/fabumexucu/edit?output

The problem is if I run the script in Firefox I get `TypeError: csv_array[i].match(...) is null`. But, if `alert` function is uncommented, I get alert of each emails in the csv file.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.